# jQuery Panels - Toggle one DIV closed before Toggling open another one!

Tags: jquery, user-interface, toggle, jquery-animate

I have the following code.

I am wondering if there is a way to detect if a panel is toggled on and if so, automatically toggle it off before toggling another one on?   This detect should happen when a user clicks the buttons.

I tried adding a "hide" function into each panel function but it didn't work as desired.  This is my current code:

```
    $(function() {
    $("#panel-2-button").click(function() {
        $("#content-inner-panel-2").toggle("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000); 
    });
    $("#panel-2-button-medium").click(function() {
        $("#content-inner-panel-2-medium").toggle("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
    });
    $("#panel-2-button-large").click(function() {
        $("#content-inner-panel-2-large").toggle("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
    });
    $("#panel-3-button").click(function() {
        $("#content-inner-panel-3").toggle("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
    });
    $("#panel-3-button-medium").click(function() {
        $("#content-inner-panel-3-medium").toggle("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
    });
    $("#panel-3-button-large").click(function() {
        $("#content-inner-panel-3-large").toggle("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
    });
    $("#panel-2-close").click(function() {
        $("#content-inner-panel-2").hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
    });
    $("#panel-2-close-medium").click(function() {
        $("#content-inner-panel-2-medium").hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
    });
    $("#panel-2-close-large").click(function() {
        $("#content-inner-panel-2-large").hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
    });
    $("#panel-3-close").click(function() {
        $("#content-inner-panel-3").hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
    });
    $("#panel-3-close-medium").click(function() {
        $("#content-inner-panel-3-medium").hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
    });
    $("#panel-3-close-large").click(function() {
        $("#content-inner-panel-3-large").hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
    });
});
```

Hope someone can help.
Zach

Comment: You could vastly reduce the amount of code by using some conventions on your IDs. Have a look at [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/TcLuf/), by changing your IDs around a bit you can replace your first 6 event handlers with 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is:

Assign a class to all the panels (like `.togglepanels`);

OnClick, first hide all the `.togglepanels` like this:

`$(".togglepanel").hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);`

then toggle open the one you want open.

Comment: I tried something like this, but it creates a very weird effect where, if you click to toggle on a DIV, it first shows the div instantly, slides it away, and then slides it back in again.   Is there a way to say something like "if .togglepanel is already hidden, do not show it and then hide it again" ?

Comment: yep, with jQuery's pseudoclasses: `$(".togglepanel:visible").hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);`

Comment: I went down a different road with my own solution - slightly different: `if ($('.togglepanel').is(':visible')) { $(".togglepanel").hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000); }`

Comment: Sorry, I am fairly new to stackoverflow, how do I award the bounty I set?

Comment: I think you just have to accept the answer, and it will be awarded at the end of the bounty time. Thanks!

Comment: You can award a bounty without marking as an answer. Also, you need to wait oned ay after the bounty period is over to award the bounty I think.

Answer (score 0):

the best way to do it is: **toggle all divs off** before toggling something on. Create a separate function for that (ToggleAllOff).

Comment: I don't see a function in jQuery called togglealloff, so what would I write in the function to toggle all divs off?

Comment: you need to implement it (simple cycle over all involved divs, turn them off one by one)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this in two steps, give a class of `panel` to all your panels.
Then use following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.panel').hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
});

$('.panel').live('click',function(){
    $('.open-panel').hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
    $(this).addClass('.open-panel').toggle("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
});
```

This code will
1. close all panel when page is loaded
2. close all open panels when any other panel is opened

Answer (score 0):

You can bind a `mousedownoutside` handler to each div and hide all others there. You'd need this [jquery plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-outside-events-plugin/) to enable the outside events.

Answer (score 0):

If I read your question correctly, you said automatically toggle it off before toggling another one on?

From jQuery docs:

```
.hide( [duration,] [easing,] [callback] )
.hide( [duration,] [callback] )
```

The callback is called after animation is complete. So after you have hidden the element you can run .toggle inside callback function. This will then toggle the other div open after the other has closed (And not closing and opening at the same time).